# Matlab2016a simulink legend

Tags: matlab, legend, simulink

I have a question about matlab**2016** simulink:

Notice:**simulink 2016**

In 2016 matlab simulink i want to set a legend on my grpah but there is no option to handle it and i don't know how to do it.please help me to do it

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a scope in Simulink to show your signal.

So double-click on the signal line to the scope and type the signal's name. Then you open the scope by a double-click, go on the configuration menu and there on the Display tab. If you check 'Show legend' there the legend should appear in the scope view displaying the signal name you typed before.